# what should i do to create custom menu appear when i click the marker instead of deleting it

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

here is my code i have done upto this point where when i add marker and hover it infowindow appears, but all of them has the same infowindow i need it to be change for each marker, second instead of clicking on the marker it gets deleted i want to creat a custom menu box on the top of marker where there should be options to add info and delete whe i click the marker.

```
<html>
<head>

<title>example</title>


<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>


<style type="text/css">

#map_canvas {
        width: 100%;
        height: 500px;
        background-color: #CCC;}

#menu_bar{
        width: 100%;
        height: 150px;
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0px;
        background-color:#008080;
        border-top:1px solid red;}

body{
        padding:0px;
        margin:0px;}




</style>
<!-- google maps Scripting start -->
<script type="text/javascript">

var markers = [];
 function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
        addMarker(event.latLng);
      });


    // add marker to positon
    function addMarker(location) {
         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: location,
                map: map
            });
            // deleting
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(event) {
        this.setMap(null);
        });

            // adding info window to gMaps


                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                         content: "holdings content area"
                    });

                     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
                         infowindow.open(map, this);
                    });

                    // assuming you also want to hide the infowindow when user mouses-out
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
                        infowindow.close();
                    });


         markers.push(marker);
        }

    // Sets the map on all markers in the array.
        function setAllMap(map) {
          for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            markers[i].setMap(map);

          }
        }

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
<!-- google maps Scripting ends -->





</head>

<body>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
<div id="menu_bar">




</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: bind onclick event to your marker at creation time and onclick launch infobox of gMap API...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a menu or popup or whatever you want in a html copy this html into javascript variable, next create gMap infoWindow and set content to your custom design, in last step bind event to your marker and in that event open your infowindow.

```
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('yourmap'), mapOptions);

  var popup= '<div>Design your whatever styled popup you want</div>';

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: popup
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'ABC'
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
  });
```